# tabulator save history in a dictionary

Tags: javascript, html, tabulator

I'm trying to save all changes made to each cell in tabulator in a list or a directory .

I've turned history feature on  `history:true,`

i've checked the "history callback" documentation in this link http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/callbacks#history and i know how to get the old and new value now but i didn't find any details about cell ID or how am i suppose to get the position or location of the changed cell

Comment: Did you try `cellEdited:function(cell){}` ?

Comment: yes it works but i want to know the location / position for the cell so i can save it in a History table on the database for later , instead of saving the whole table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cell component passed into any of the callbacks like ***cellEdited*** gives you access to the cell directly.

It can also give you access to row and column information too.

For example you can get the field that the cell relates to by calling the ***getField*** function on the component, you can access the column component which will give you access to all sorts of useful column related info

```
cellEdited:function(cell){
    //cell - cell component

   var field = cell.getField();
   var column = cell.getColumn();
},
```

if you want to know which row was edited then you can use the ***getData*** function on the cell component to return the rows data object, then lookup whatever unique identifying field you have setup (for example an id field if you have set one). you can also get the row component by using the ***getRow*** function which will give you access to all sorts of useful row related info including the ***getPosition*** function which will tell you the vertical position of the row in the table.

```
cellEdited:function(cell){
    //cell - cell component

   var id = cell.getData().id;
   var row = cell.getRow();
   var position = row.getPosition();
},
```

Have a look at the [Component Objects Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/components) for full details

Comment: console.log(row.getPosition()) , it says in chromes console "is not a function "

Comment: sorry there was an error in the example, which i have now fixed, it should have said var row = cell.getRow();